# rally iteration combobox returns empty

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I'm new to rally app SDK and trying to do the tutorials (from Youtube and from rally site)
when I'm trying to create an iterationComboBox the object is created but with no values ("There are no Iterations defined").
i tried to run both the video tutorial code from github (session_4_interactive_grid)

```
// Custom Rally App that displays Defects in a grid and filter by Iteration and/or Severity.
//
// Note: various console debugging messages intentionally kept in the code for learning purposes

Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',      // The parent class manages the app 'lifecycle' and calls launch() when ready
    componentCls: 'app',          // CSS styles found in app.css


    defectStore: undefined,       // app level references to the store and grid for easy access in various methods
    defectGrid: undefined,

    // Entry Point to App
    launch: function() {

      console.log('our second app');     // see console api: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api

      this.pulldownContainer = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {    // this container lets us control the layout of the pulldowns; they'll be added below
        id: 'pulldown-container-id',
        layout: {
                type: 'hbox',           // 'horizontal' layout
                align: 'stretch'
            }
      });

      this.add(this.pulldownContainer); // must add the pulldown container to the app to be part of the rendering lifecycle, even though it's empty at the moment

       this._loadIterations();
    },

    // create iteration pulldown and load iterations
    _loadIterations: function() {
        this.iterComboBox = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.IterationComboBox', {
          fieldLabel: 'Iteration',
          labelAlign: 'right',
          width: 300,
          listeners: {
            ready: function(combobox) {             // on ready: during initialization of the app, once Iterations are loaded, lets go get Defect Severities
                 this._loadSeverities();
           },
        select: function(combobox, records) {   // on select: after the app has fully loaded, when the user 'select's an iteration, lets just relaod the data
                 this._loadData();
           },
           scope: this
         }
        });

            this.pulldownContainer.add(this.iterComboBox);   // add the iteration list to the pulldown container so it lays out horiz, not the app!
     },

    // create defect severity pulldown then load data
    _loadSeverities: function() {
        this.severityComboBox = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.FieldValueComboBox', {
          model: 'Defect',
          field: 'Severity',
          fieldLabel: 'Severity',
          labelAlign: 'right',
          listeners: {
            ready: function(combobox) {             // this is the last 'data' pulldown we're loading so both events go to just load the actual defect data
                 this._loadData();
           },
            select: function(combobox, records) {
                 this._loadData();
           },
           scope: this                              // <--- don't for get to pass the 'app' level scope into the combo box so the async event functions can call app-level func's!
         }

        });

        this.pulldownContainer.add(this.severityComboBox);    // add the severity list to the pulldown container so it lays out horiz, not the app!
     },

    // Get data from Rally
    _loadData: function() {

      var selectedIterRef = this.iterComboBox.getRecord().get('_ref');              // the _ref is unique, unlike the iteration name that can change; lets query on it instead!
      var selectedSeverityValue = this.severityComboBox.getRecord().get('value');   // remember to console log the record to see the raw data and relize what you can pluck out

      console.log('selected iter', selectedIterRef);
      console.log('selected severity', selectedSeverityValue);

      var myFilters = [                   // in this format, these are AND'ed together; use Rally.data.wsapi.Filter to create programatic AND/OR constructs
            {
              property: 'Iteration',
              operation: '=',
              value: selectedIterRef
            },
            {
              property: 'Severity',
              operation: '=',
              value: selectedSeverityValue
            }
          ];

      // if store exists, just load new data
      if (this.defectStore) {
        console.log('store exists');
        this.defectStore.setFilter(myFilters);
        this.defectStore.load();

      // create store
      } else {
        console.log('creating store');
        this.defectStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {     // create defectStore on the App (via this) so the code above can test for it's existence!
          model: 'Defect',
          autoLoad: true,                         // <----- Don't forget to set this to true! heh
          filters: myFilters,
          listeners: {
              load: function(myStore, myData, success) {
                  console.log('got data!', myStore, myData);
                  if (!this.defectGrid) {           // only create a grid if it does NOT already exist
                        this._createGrid(myStore);      // if we did NOT pass scope:this below, this line would be incorrectly trying to call _createGrid() on the store which does not exist.
                  }
              },
              scope: this                         // This tells the wsapi data store to forward pass along the app-level context into ALL listener functions
          },
          fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Severity', 'Iteration']   // Look in the WSAPI docs online to see all fields available!
        });
      }
    },

    // Create and Show a Grid of given defect
    _createGrid: function(myDefectStore) {

      this.defectGrid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
        store: myDefectStore,
        columnCfgs: [         // Columns to display; must be the same names specified in the fetch: above in the wsapi data store
          'FormattedID', 'Name', 'Severity', 'Iteration'
        ]
      });

      this.add(this.defectGrid);       // add the grid Component to the app-level Container (by doing this.add, it uses the app container)

    }

});
```

and the code from Rally site (https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/guide/first_app).
        // Custom Rally App that displays Defects in a grid and filter by Iteration and/or Severity.
        //
        // Note: various console debugging messages intentionally kept in the code for learning purposes

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',      // The parent class manages the app 'lifecycle' and calls launch() when ready
    componentCls: 'app',          // CSS styles found in app.css

        launch: function() {
        this.iterationCombobox = this.add({
            xtype: 'rallyiterationcombobox',
            listeners: {
                change: this._onIterationComboboxChanged,
                ready: this._onIterationComboboxLoad,
                scope: this
            }
        });
    },

    _onIterationComboboxLoad: function() {
        var addNewConfig = {
            xtype: 'rallyaddnew',
            recordTypes: ['User Story', 'Defect'],
            ignoredRequiredFields: ['Name', 'ScheduleState', 'Project'],
            showAddWithDetails: false,
            listeners: {
                beforecreate: this._onBeforeCreate,
                scope: this
            }
        };

        this.addNew = this.add(addNewConfig);

        var cardBoardConfig = {
            xtype: 'rallycardboard',
            types: ['Defect', 'User Story'],
            attribute: 'ScheduleState',
            storeConfig: {
                filters: [this.iterationCombobox.getQueryFromSelected()]
            }
        };
        this.cardBoard = this.add(cardBoardConfig);       
    },

    _onBeforeCreate: function(addNewComponent, record) {
        record.set('Iteration', this.iterationCombobox.getValue());
    },

    _onIterationComboboxChanged: function() {
        var config = {
            storeConfig: {
                filters: [this.iterationCombobox.getQueryFromSelected()]
            }
        };

        this.cardBoard.refresh(config);
    }
});
```

both give me an empty iteration box.

i'm getting user stories data when running code from session 3 on the video,by creating a store of user stories. I googled it and searched here for duplicates but with no successso far, so what can be the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code you posted, both apps, without making any changes, ran the apps and the iteration box was populated in both cases. It's not the code.
Maybe if you are getting "There are no Iterations defined" there are no iterations in your project?
The second code you posted which you copied from the example in the documentation has a bug in it and even though the iteration combobox is populated, the cards do not show on a board. DevTools console has error: "Cannot read property 'refresh' of undefined".

I have a working version of this app [in this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/story-board).

Comment: Thanks for the reply
We have many of iterations in out project(s).
I ran the apps from another machine logged in to the same workspace and project in Rally and got no results.
I also ran your app and got no results. 
I'll check it with my organization and rally support.
Thanks!